# How to play SWF file in .NET 4.0 C# WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, .net-4.0, shockwave

I have a SWF file which i want to be usable offline aswell. I have searched for how to play SWF files. But it doesn't work when i put a WebBrowser component ( it displays a save file dialog.. ). I have also seen that can use the AxShockwaveFlash COM component ( I myself used it in an application for .net 3.5 , AxShockwaveFlash doesnt show up when i browse for it in the .NET 4.0 application). cant find anything else for .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually AxShockwaveFlash works, it didnt show up because of a wrong flash player version. what's needed is "Adobe Flash Player XX ActiveX" XX = latest version number.